# How to Saveing page views in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have page where I show 50 images to the user and user can click on the image and will load just this image in another page. Now I want to save every image view to a database i.e. counter for the clicked imageID. 
So what I've made so far is to add another row into table which I called `hits`. Here I show the images:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT $start_from, 50");
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
{
   echo '                                   
         <h1><a href="post.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a></h1>
         <img src="../upload/'.$row['name'].'" alt=""/>';
}
```

In `post.php` where user see only this image which he clicked on I have this:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
   $id = $_GET['id'];                         
   $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id= ?");
   if ($result->execute(array($_GET['id']))) 
   {            
       for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++)
       {
           echo '    
               // source to show that image
               ';
       }
   }
}
```

What I understand I must update the `hits` row with something like this

```
UPDATE images SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE id = idofimage
```

What I can't understand is how to implement the update in current code. Also where?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have everything solved

Just add the update code in the same place you are displaying the image

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
{
   $id = $_GET['id'];                         
   $result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id= ?");
   if ($result->execute(array($_GET['id']))) 
   {       
       //replace for by if because we are only getting one result  
       if($row = $result->fetch())
       {
           //update the hits
           $update = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE images SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE id = ?");
           //I prefer binding values and have a call to execute()
           //but both options are ok
           //$update->bindParam(1, $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
           //$update->execute();
           $update->execute(array($_GET['id']));

           echo '    
               // source to show that image
               ';
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer and corrected my code. Actually I really don't need `for` and `array`. But this doesn't update hits in the database.

Comment: You have `=>` instead of `=` where is UPDATE query. Also on line `$update->execute($_GET['id']);` I've go error that expecting array but string given so I make it again `->execute(array($_GET['id']))`. And now is working.

Comment: Corrected the syntax :)

Comment: Thank's for the answer. What is the different between you answer and @Jason's answer. I mean is it better to update the hits first or first to show image and ensure that is exist and then update. I believe your solution is for this.. to be sure that there is image with this ID?

Answer (score 0):

You must make UPDATE statement and then SELECT to show that single image. Should be something like this:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE images SET hits = hits + 1 WHERE id = ?");
$result->execute(array($_GET['id']));
$result = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id= ?");
if ($result->execute(array($_GET['id']))) {
     // .. rest of the code
```

Note: Is not tested and I'm also still learning PHP&MySQL so if there is better solution please correct me. 
Thank's.

Comment: Your solution is almost identical as mine, but I prefer to do the update after I have checked the image exists

Comment: Yes, your solution is better. I forgot to check if the image actually exist. Thank's for the comment and correcting me!